# How I can do query by spark SQL when I add cloumn auto increase by querying

Tags: sql, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

I do this query in MySQL like this:

```
SELECT *,@a:=@a+1 AS rn FROM PERSON,(SELECT(@a:=0)) AS A
```

I want to know how I can do this by spark sql when I query a DataFrame,like this type:

```
val strSQL=" SELECT *,@a:=@a+1 AS rn FROM PERSON,(SELECT(@a:=0)) AS A"
sqlContext.sql(strSQL)
```

My problem is that when I run this code ,the console tell me  @a:=@a+1 is wrong, I dont knwon how to write the SQL in spark SQL type.

Comment: Are you trying to imitate Rownum or LAG? If yes, windowing functions are already implemented in Spark.

Comment: what is `@a:=@a+1` ?

Comment: yes,I want to generate Rownum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to generate row number then you can use the function

```
val schema = df.schema //data frame schema 

//add rowNumberField
val rows = df.rdd.zipWithUniqueId.map{
   case (r: Row, id: Long) => Row.fromSeq(id +: r.toSeq)}

Create DataFrame with schema 

val dfWithPK = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
  rows, StructType(StructField("rowMunber", LongType, false) +: schema.fields))
```

You can also use SQL function to generate row number

```
sqlContext.sql("select row_number() over (order by columnName) as rowNumber from Person")
```

Or you can use use  Using MontotonicallyIncreasingID methodto generate unique row Ids.

```
df.withColumn("RowNumber",monotonicallyIncreasingId)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Point to note here, `monotonicallyIncreasingID` generates non-deterministic values in increasing order. Not exactly what the OP wants.